# react-router v4 : how do you handle "/" page as synonym for other page?

Tags: react-router-v4

I have a server that renders the same single page app for multiple URLS :

```
/
/A
/B
```

I want A to act as a "Home" page. 
So a browser request to "/" or "/A" should display the same thing.

In particular, I'll have links to pages A and B, and I want the link to A to be marked as active for "/" and "/A".

So I'm using something like :

```
<NavLink to="/A" activeClassName='nav-active'>Go to A</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/B" activeClassName='nav-active'>Go to B</NavLink>

<Router>
 <Route path='/A' component={A} />
 <Route path='/B' component={B} />
</Router>
```

How would I make "/" as a synonym for "/A" ? What I tried :

- adding another `Route` with `path="/"` : this results in two components being displayed
- using a regexp like `path="/(A)?"` : this displays the right component, but the link ist not marked as active

Should I implement it as a server side redirect instead (just making `/` redirect to `/A` rather than serving the same page content ?)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a `Redirect` does the trick

```
<Router>
 <Route path='/A' component={A} />
 <Route path='/B' component={B} />
 <Route path='/' render={() => (
   <Redirect to='/A' />
 )} />  
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `exact={true}`

```
<Router>
  <Route path='/' exact={true} component={A} />
  <Route path='/A' exact={true} component={A} />
  <Route path='/B' exact={true} component={B} />  
 </Router>
```